# Is NAudio capable of playing audio CDs (CDA files)?

Tags: naudio

If yes, which NAudio API will work. My preference is WaveOut if it is able.
Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, NAudio does not play audio CDs. You need to look into the MCI_PLAY command to do that in Windows. It's not something very commonly needed these days.